# Use Crispy Form with a ListView

Tags: python, django, forms, listview, django-crispy-forms

I am pretty new to Python and Django, but what I am trying to do is to use a Crispy Form in one of my template that is loaded with a ListView type of view. I usually load all of my other templates from a UpdateView which provide everything Crispy need already. I can't change the type of view here so I have to stick with the ListView but when I try to load the form, Crispy can't find it. I don't know how to provide the form to the template manually.

Here is what I have so far:

My template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load i18n %}
{% load tz %}

  {% block content %}

  {% crispy form %}

  <!-- template content -->      

  {% endblock %}
```

My form.py

```
class UserBirthdayForm(forms.ModelForm):
    birth_day = forms.IntegerField(required=True, localize=True, label=_('*My birth day'))
    birth_month = forms.IntegerField(required=True, localize=True, label=_('*My birth month'))
    birth_year = forms.IntegerField(required=True, localize=True, label=_('*My birth year'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Div('birth_day', css_class='col-sm-4'),
                Div('birth_month', css_class='col-sm-4'),
                Div('birth_year', css_class='col-sm-4'),
                css_class='row'
            ),
            Submit('save', _('update'), css_class='pull-right'),
        )

    class Meta():
        model = User

        fields = ("birth_day", "birth_month", "birth_year")
```

My view.py:

```
class MissionList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    form_class = UserBirthdayForm

    def get_queryset(self):
        #some other stuff
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #some other stuff
        return context
```

Here is the error I get from Django when trying to access the page:

`VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [form] in u"[some other stuff]"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `get_context_data` create an instance of your form and add it to the context.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    #some other stuff — where you create `context`

    context["form"] = UserBirthdayForm()

    return context
```

Comment: I have already tried, it doesn't work, I have this error : `TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type`

Comment: OK. So your form is broken... super(UserForm, self)... — Your form's class is UserBirthdayForm not UserForm.